# SQL Server: Recursive Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, hierarchy

I've been struggling trying to write the logic to show a relationship between interrelated records.

Here is some sample data to show what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_data 
(
 item_id  int,
 item_name  varchar(100),
 related_item_id  int,
 related_item_name  varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #temp_data 
select 10, 'apple', 20 , 'orange' UNION ALL
select 20, 'orange', 30 , 'grape' UNION ALL
select 30, 'orange', NULL , NULL UNION ALL
select 100, 'tomato', 200 , 'onion' UNION ALL
select 200, 'onion', 300 , 'tomato' UNION ALL
select 400, 'cucumber',100 , 'tomato' UNION ALL
select 300, 'pepper', NULL , NULL UNION ALL     
select 500, 'lettuce', 400 , 'cucumber' UNION ALL 
select 1000, 'beef' , NULL, NULL   UNION ALL 
select 10000, 'cheese, NULL, NULL
```

Expected Results:

```
    group_id    item_id item_name   related_item_id related_item_name
    1           10      apple       20              orange
    1           20      orange      30              grape
    1           30      orange      NULL            NULL
    2           100     tomato      200             onion
    2           200     onion       300             tomato
    2           300     pepper      NULL            NULL
    2           400     cucumber     100            tomato
    2           500     lettuce     400             cucumber
    3           1000    beef        NULL            NULL
    4           10000   cheese      NULL            NULL
```

I tried to accomplish this through a recursive CTE, but I had not luck.

Comment: Please edit your post to show your attempted CTE, and what was wrong with the results.

Comment: The data posted above was just some sample data to illustrate an example. I'm trying to figure out how to write the logic to show the relationship between the records with matching item_id / related_item_ids. For instance, A = B, and B = C, I'm having trouble writing the logic to show A = C.

Comment: Could there be a group of items where one of them doesn't have `related_item_id = NULL`?  Is the relationship always a simple tree, or could there be cycles in the relations between items?  If either of these is true, then the answer would be different.  A key part of example data is making sure it completely captures the nuances and complications relevant to your actual data set.

Comment: Mellamokb, that's a great point. Yes, the example you gave can occur. I have updated my sample data to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is one solution**

```
;WITH T AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_id) AS group_id,
        *
    FROM #temp_data T
    WHERE related_item_Id IS NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT T.group_id, T1.*
    FROM T
        INNER JOIN #temp_data T1
            ON T.item_id = T1.related_item_id
)

SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY group_id, item_id
```

**The output is**

```
group_id             item_id     item_name       related_item_id related_item_name
-------------------- ----------- --------------- --------------- -----------------
1                    10          apple           20              orange
1                    20          orange          30              grape
1                    30          grape           NULL            NULL
2                    100         tomato          200             onion
2                    200         onion           300             tomato
2                    300         pepper          NULL            NULL
2                    400         cucumber        100             tomato
2                    500         lettuce         400             cucumber
```

Comment: SQLFiddle with the solution (expanded a bit for readability): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/919d8/11